# Convert a string to hex number?

Tags: string-manipulation, number-representation

How can I convert a string containing a hex number such as `"6b"` to a hex digit that *mathematica* can use to do math with?

I have tried using `ToExpression["6b"]` but that just give me another string.

Note: Java's `BigInteger`class can construct hex integers from strings.  Is there something like this in *mathematica*?

Comment: By the way, the returned value is *not* another string. It's the expression 6 b. If you do `FullForm[ToExpression["6b"]]` you will see its true form. One thing that makes Mathematica unusual as far as programming languages go is that unassigned symbols (like b in this case) have their own values. They aren't strings and they aren't "variables". They're symbols and they can be passed around like any other value. In Java-speak you can think of them as sort of like enums.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function converting strings to integer is `FromDigits`. It is the counterpart of `IntegerString` and both functions can be used with whatever basis you like. Therefore, if you want to convert from base 16 you do

```
FromDigits["6b", 16]
```

Comment: And how could you take floating numbers? as `FromDigits["5AF.D2", 16]`

Answer (score 8):

```
stringToHex[str_] := ToExpression["16^^" <> str];
```

This is just a way of automating the normal notation you would use, which is 16^^6b (check [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InputSyntax.html) for the documentation).

Comment: Your stringToHex function is converting a hexadecimal to decimal. The string argument passed contains the hex digits. Therefore, the name of the function should be changed to something like hexStringToDecimal. But this is already implemented with FromDigits[hexString, 16] as halirutan said.