# How to convert a hex color string to RGBColor?

Tags: color

For example: `"#FF8000"`.

How could I convert it to `RGBColor` or `Hue`?

Comment: Incidentally, this site, among many others, also uses three character color codes (#888). Should answers accept both forms?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using `IntegerDigits` to convert directly to base 256:

```
hexToRGB = RGBColor @@ (IntegerDigits[
  ToExpression@StringReplace[#, "#" -> "16^^"], 256, 3]/255.) &

hexToRGB["#FF8000"]
(*   RGBColor[1., 0.501961, 0.]  *)
```

**Edit**

Shorter version, since somebody mentioned golfing...

```
hexToRGB = RGBColor @@ (IntegerDigits[# ~StringDrop~ 1 ~FromDigits~ 16, 256, 3]/255.) &
```

Comment: That is a particularly clever solution...

Comment: Yup, very nice indeed

Comment: Why the "3" in the golfed version?

Comment: @belisarius, you need to pad to 3 digits in case the red component is zero

Comment: Ok, true. I forgot that

Comment: Again we think alike.  You're even using infix!  FWIW when using infix I recommend the spacing that I just edited your post to include.  I think it's much more readable that way, and I can tell you from experience that a lot of people find it hard to read anyway.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks for the edit - I agree it's more readable like that.

Answer (score 21):

Starting from version **10.1** you can use `RGBColor` directly:

```
RGBColor["#FF8000"]
(* RGBColor[1., 0.5019607843137255, 0.] *)

RGBColor["#45A"]
(* RGBColor[0.26666666666666666`, 0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666] *)

ToColor[RGBColor["#FF8000"], Hue]
(* Hue[0.08366013071895424, 1., 1.] *)
```

Answer (score 12):

Function that converts string to a list of 3 numbers: for R, G and B component:

```
toRGBSequence[i_] := 
  Composition[FromDigits[#, 16] &, StringJoin] /@ 
   Partition[Characters[StringDrop[i, 1]], 2] /. List -> Sequence;
```

- First, dropping the `#` sign.
- Converting to a list, using the `Characters` function.
- Partitioning in groups of 2.
- Composition of function to first join the two letters and than convert it to a base-10 format.
- Map over a list.
- Converting everything to `Sequence` to use with `RGBColor` function.

Usage:

```
RGBColor[toRGBSequence["#FF5500"]]
```

**PS:** This may, or may not be the most accurate and fast solution.

Comment: +1 it's more beautiful than mine is, that's for sure :)

Answer (score 10):

I hate regular expressions... :)

```
hexColorToRGB[s_] := RGBColor[FromDigits[#, 16]/255 & /@ Flatten[
  StringCases[ToLowerCase@s,
   {RegularExpression[
    "#([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})" ] 
      -> {"$1", "$2", "$3"},
    RegularExpression["#([0-9a-f])([0-9a-f])([0-9a-f])"] 
      -> {"$1$1", "$2$2", "$3$3"}}
 ]]]

ColorSetter /@ 
 hexColorToRGB /@ 
    {"#000", "#FF0000", "#0F0", "#0000FF", "#FF0", 
     "#00FFFF", "#F0F", "#C0C0C0", "#FFF"}
```

[image: test]

Answer (score 8):

Here is another option:

```
hexToRGB =
  RGBColor[ FromDigits[#, 16]/255 & /@ StringTake[#, {{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}}] ] &;

hexToRGB@"#FF8c00" // ColorSetter
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And another:

```
hexToRGB =
  RGBColor[ FromDigits[#, 16]/255 & /@ StringCases[#, Except["#"] ~~ _] ] &;
```

---

### `#RGB` form

Responding to cormullion's comment:

```
hexToRGB[color_String | {colors__String}] :=
  RGBColor[FromDigits[#, 16]/255 & /@ #] & @@@
    StringCases[{color, colors},
      {"#" ~~ r_ ~~ g_ ~~ b_ ~~ EndOfString :> {r ~~ r, g ~~ g, b ~~ b},
       "#" ~~ r : (_ ~~ _) ~~ g : (_ ~~ _) ~~ b : (_ ~~ _) :> {r, g, b}}]

ColorSetter /@ hexToRGB @ 
  {"#000", "#FF0000", "#0F0", "#0000FF", "#FF0", "#00FFFF", "#F0F", "#C0C0C0", "#FFF"}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Operating on the entire list of color strings should be faster than one at a time.

Comment: I really like the second one...

Answer (score 7):

Also

```
rgb[x_] := RGBColor[FromDigits[#, 2] / 255 & /@ 
            Partition[IntegerDigits[FromDigits[StringDrop[x, 1], 16], 2, 24], 8]]

rgb@"#FF5500"
```

> RGBColor[{255, 85, 0}]

**Edit**

Golfing a one liner :)

```
rgb[x_] := RGBColor[FromDigits[#, 16]/255 & /@ StringJoin /@ Partition[Rest@Characters@x, 2]]
```

Comment: You need to work on your swing: `rgb[x_] := RGBColor[FromDigits["" <> # , 16]/255 & /@ Rest@Characters@x ~Partition~ 2]` or fully Golfed: `rgb=RGBColor[FromDigits[""<>#,16]/255&/@Rest@Characters@#~Partition~2]&`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Good one :). I wasn't golfing seriously, just trying to fit it in one line. Simon's answer is far better, anyway

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty miffed he got that one before me. :o)

Answer (score 7):

In version 10

```
Interpreter["StructuredColor"]["#FF8000"]
```

> RGBColor[1, Rational[128, 255], 0]

Answer (score 6):

You guys are too fast for me ;)

My solution which is similar to @cormullion's:

```
hexToRGB[hex_String] :=Module[{RGB},
    RGB = StringCases[hex, 
       RegularExpression["^#(\\w{2})(\\w{2})(\\w{2})"] -> {"$1", "$2", 
        "$3"}] // Flatten;
    RGBColor[FromDigits[#, 16]/100 - 1 & /@ RGB]
]

Graphics[{hexToRGB["#A4A4A4"], Disk[]}]
```

P.S.: Things are not always just `#000000` and `#FFFFFF`. It's mostly varying of shades of `#A4A4A4` :)

***EDIT***

PieChart of the sector angles proportional to {R, G, B}

```
hexToPiechart =PieChart3D @@ {ToExpression@#/255. & /@ (StringCases[#, 
    RegularExpression["^#(\\w{2})(\\w{2})(\\w{2})"] -> {"16^^$1", 
      "16^^$2", "16^^$3"}])} &;


hexToPiechart["#A4A4A4"]
```

[image: pie chart]

Answer (score 5):

Borrowing from [amr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/950/amr?tab=answers)'s answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11089/106)

```
ToExpression["16^^" <> #] & /@ 
   Partition[Characters@StringTrim[#, "#"], 2] & /@ {"FFFFFF", 
  "#FFFFFF", "000000", "#FF5500", "#005500"}
```

=>{{255, 255, 255}, {255, 255, 255}, {0, 0, 0}, {255, 85, 0}, {0, 85, 
  0}}

Answer (score 5):

```
 ColorData["WebSafe", "Panel"] (*click to get RGBColor *)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just to add nothing to the previous answers

```
toRGB[str_String]:=ToExpression["16^^" <> #] & /@ 
  str~StringDrop~1~StringCases~Repeated[_, {2}] /. 
 List -> RGBColor
```