# How can I import html fragments as formatted cells?

Tags: front-end, import, html, style, cells

I see that there is limited support for "HTMLFragment" in Export, but I figured with all the work that went into porting Mathematica into the Wolfram Cloud there should be a way to Import "HTMLFragments".

Here is the fragment I'd like to import into a cell/box expression:

```
    <div style=\"text-align: center;\">
    This is <span style=\"font-size: 21px;\">
    <i>an example</i></span> of a <u>
    <font face=\"Georgia\" style=\"font-size: 19px;\">text cell</font></u> with 
<font color=\"#c14dff\" style=\"\">complex styles</font> applied.</div>
```

So this would look like this:
[image]

Comment: p.s. Import it as XML and define rules for your transformation. There is also a tutorial about working with XML.

Comment: @Kuba I added an image of what it should render to.

Comment: You can start with this: `Block[{XMLElement, f},
 
 
 XMLElement[tag_, opt_, content_] := 
  Tooltip[Row[content, " "], f[opt]];
 xml[[2]]
 ]`

Answer (score 3):

OP's stuff:

```
html = "<div style=\"text-align: center;\">
      This is <span style=\"font-size: 21px;\">
      <i>an example</i></span> of a <u>
      <font face=\"Georgia\" style=\"font-size: 19px;\">text \
cell</font></u> with 
  <font color=\"#c14dff\" style=\"\">complex styles</font> \
applied.</div>";
```

[Simon Woods color converter:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18506/5478)

```
hexToRGB = RGBColor @@ (IntegerDigits[ ToExpression@StringReplace[#, "#" -> "16^^"], 256, 3]/255.) &
```

Auxiliary functions, you have to extend them for proper interpretation of all rules...

```
lhs[name_String] := Switch[name,
   "face", FontFamily,
   "font-size", FontSize,
   "color", FontColor,
   "text-align", TextAlignment,
   "center", Center,
   _, name
   ];

rhs[string_String] :=  Composition[ToExpression, lhs, 
    StringReplace[#, {"px" -> "", color : ("#" ~~ __) :> ToString[hexToRGB[color]]}] &,  StringTrim][string];

style[opt : {__}] := (style /@ opt);
style[{} | ""] := {};
style["style" -> (dir_)] := style[dir];
style[(l_) -> (r_)] := lhs[l] -> rhs[r];
style[s_String] := Sequence @@ (lhs[#] -> rhs[#2] & @@@ Partition[StringSplit[s, ";" | ":"], 2]);
```

Procedure:

```
xml = ImportString[html, "XML"];


Block[{XMLElement},

 XMLElement["div", opt_, content_] := Cell[BoxData@RowBox@content, style@opt];
 XMLElement["i", opt_, content_] := StyleBox[RowBox@content, Italic];
 XMLElement["u", opt_, content_] := StyleBox[RowBox@content, Underlined];
 XMLElement[tag_, opt_, content_] := StyleBox[RowBox[Riffle[content, " "]], style@opt];

 CellPrint@xml[[2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: A bit telegraphic, but it seems to do the job :-) +1

Comment: @chris You mean I should add explanations? Let's say I will answer any question instead :) There is to much t write to make nice tutorial. Shortly, those are just DownValues for `XMLElements` and `style` parser.

Comment: Its perfectly fine. It just feels you were in a bit of a rush.

Comment: @chris I always am, I should try to learn better time management :/