# How do you convert RGBColor to an HTML-style string?

Tags: color

If I run some color processing function, like:

```
Blend[RGBColor /@ {"#DC4E00", "#000000", "#822250", "#FCC11B"}]
```

I get back a `RGBColor` object:

```
RGBColor[0.5901960784313726, 0.29901960784313725, 0.10490196078431373]
```

Is there a simple way to convert that `RGBColor` to an HTML string, like:

```
"#813912"
```

Comment: closely related [18495](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18495/5478)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5637709

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems like the function I was wanting was:

```
hexifyColor[color_RGBColor] := 
  StringJoin["#", IntegerString[Round[Level[color, 1]*255], 16, 2]]
```

Answer (score 6):

It is there, deep down, but I'm too lazy to dig...

```
hexColor = StringCases[
    ExportString[Style[1, #], "HTMLFragment"], 
    "color:" ~~ color__ ~~ "\"" :> color
][[1]] &


hexColor@Blue
```

> ```
> "#0000ff"
> ```