# Can you change mathematica's RGBcolor scheme from Arithmetic to Digital 8-bit per channel?

Tags: color

When you define a new color using the RGBcolor function the system used is the arithmetic where color are defined by values between 0 and 1, I think.

Is there a way to use the Digital 8-bit per channel system instead? The one that ranges from 0 to 255.

Thank you.

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18495)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say you want to define a color with 8-bit RGB values {100, 125, 240}. You could use:

```
col = {100, 125, 240};
RGBColor[col/255]
```

Answer (score 4):

A couple more ways:

```
RGBColor["#" <> IntegerString[{10, 125, 240}, 16, 2]]

First@DominantColors@Image[{{{10, 125, 240}}}, "Byte"]
```

Output:

```
(*  RGBColor[0.0392156862745098, 0.49019607843137253`, 0.9411764705882353]  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

The `Interpreter` function does direct conversion of color specifications.

```
Interpreter["Color"]["RGB 64 128 255"]
(* RGBColor[64/255, 128/255, 1] *)
```

Note that use of "Color" requires connectivity to the Wolfram Cloud.