# How can I tell Mathematica to interpret 0xffff as a hexadecimal number?

Tags: formatting, custom-notation

I am stuck. I would like *Mathematica* simply accept `0x` as a prefix Operator for Hexadecimal Numbers. I know that `0x` is interpreted as `0*x`, so maybe this is just not possible. I am a programmer and am so used to type something like `0xffff` instead of `16^^ffff` ...

Comment: There is a topic about conversion from string if that is fine with you.

Comment: Closely related: [How to convert a hex color string to RGBColor?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18495/5478)

Comment: @Alexey: Thanks for the edit !

Answer (score 19):

**Update**

As pointed out by @Edmund, my initial answer didn't work with hex numbers starting with an integer. To fix that, I included an initial `\[DiscretionaryHyphen]` character, and then I drop that character when converting to a number using [`FromDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits) *(my first update used `x`, but I like this new approach better)*:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = {
    "0x" -> RowBox[{
        InterpretationBox[
            StyleBox["\"0x\"", "Inactive", ShowStringCharacters->False],
            Function[Null, FromDigits[StringDrop[ToString@Unevaluated@#, 1], 16], HoldAll]
        ],
        "\[InvisibleApplication]",
        "\[InvisibleSpace]",
        StyleBox["\[DiscretionaryHyphen]", ShowAutoStyles->False]
    }],
    ParentList
};
```

Edmund also points out that you can use my original approach, you just need to include quotes if the hex number starts with an integer.

**Initial answer**

If you are satisfied with an [`InputAliases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAliases) approach, you could try:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = {
    "0x" -> RowBox[{
        InterpretationBox[
            StyleBox["\"0x\"", "Inactive", ShowStringCharacters -> False],
            Function[Null, FromDigits[ToString@Unevaluated@#, 16], HoldAll]
        ],
        "\[InvisibleApplication]",
        "\[InvisibleSpace]"
    }],
    ParentList
};
```

Here is an animation showing the alias in action:

[image]

Comment: Learned a lot from this. Thanks! (+1)

Comment: Your usage wipes all the existing input aliases out of the `InputAliases` option.  Perhaps you could update to append this the existing list of input aliases.

Comment: @Edmund See update.

Comment: Humm, there seems to be an issue with this solution when the hex numbers do not begin with a character. It works for `f6` but not `6f`.  Is there a way to fix this? Well, you can just do `"6f"` in these cases. Perhaps best to always use the quotes?

Comment: @Edmund I added a version that starts the hex number with x so that mixtures of integers and letters can be added on. Then the interpretation function drops the x and converts to an integer.

Comment: Nice approach.  I was trying to  use `Invisible` to prepend but was having problems getting it to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Carl !!!

Comment: How did you produce your answer-animation?

Answer (score 10):

One approach is to the use that [Notation Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html)'s [`AddInputAlias`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/ref/AddInputAlias.html) function to setup an alias that will convert <kbd>Esc</kbd> 0x <kbd>Esc</kbd> to `16^^` when you type it.

First load the notation package with

```
Needs["Notation`"]
```

You can then view all the active notation aliases with

```
ActiveInputAliases[]
```

One of these in the list is an input alias to **add** **i**nput **a**lias (**addia**).

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

In a new cell type <kbd>Esc</kbd> addia <kbd>Esc</kbd>

This converts to the add input alias template.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Enter `0x` in the quoted box and `16^^` in the template box.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then evaluate the cell.

Now evaluating `ActiveInputAliases[]` again will show the new `0x` alias in the list.

To use simply type <kbd>Esc</kbd> 0x <kbd>Esc</kbd> in any expression and it will be converted to `16^^`. Then just type your hexadecimal number.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Edmund, this works, but then I have to type 'Esc' 0x 'Esc' and this then converts automatically to 16^^. I want the Expression to stay in the form 0xabcd and evaluated like usual, e.g. as a hexadecimal number.

Comment: @Mark I think you will be hard pressed to have that result because the *operator* you want to use `0x` starts with a digit and the WolframLanguage does not like that. Perhaps one of the gurus around here can do something fancy with boxes and `Formal`.  This will most likely add extra steps for others to work with your code.  In the end you many have to simply accept the syntax of the Wolfram Language.

Comment: I think you are right. I just was hoping to find some simple solution, but I guess I will just have to use 16^^. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, I propose to work with strings:

```
Hex[x_?StringQ] := "16^^" <> StringJoin@Take[Characters@x, {3, Length[Characters@x]}]
```

So:

```
Hex@"0xff065"   (* 16^^ff065 *)
ToExpression@Hex["0xff065"]   (* 1044581 *)
```

and

```
BaseForm[1044581, 16]
```

$\text{ff065}_{16}$

Comment: Thank you José, not yet what I want but another way to think about it !