# Difference between ParentList and Inherited

Tags: front-end, undocumented

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161658/38205) Carl Woll uses the `ParentList` symbol to inherit old input aliases when adding a new one:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   InputAliases] = {"0x" -> 
    RowBox[{InterpretationBox[
       StyleBox["\"0\"", ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
       Function[Null, 
        FromDigits[StringDrop[ToString@Unevaluated@#, 1], 16], 
        HoldAll]], "\[InvisibleApplication]", "\[InvisibleSpace]", 
      StyleBox["x", ShowAutoStyles -> False]}], ParentList};
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] /. Rule[a_, _] :> a

{"0x", ParentList}
```

And we can still use the all the basic built-in aliases

On the other-hand, we can get the same result using `Inherited`:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = Inherited;
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   InputAliases] = {"0x" -> 
    RowBox[{InterpretationBox[
       StyleBox["\"0\"", ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
       Function[Null, 
        FromDigits[StringDrop[ToString@Unevaluated@#, 1], 16], 
        HoldAll]], "\[InvisibleApplication]", "\[InvisibleSpace]", 
      StyleBox["x", ShowAutoStyles -> False]}], Inherited};
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] /. Rule[a_, _] :> a

{"0x", Inherited}
```

And we can, again, use the all of the built-in aliases, but if we look at the `AbsoluteCurrentValue`s for the first case:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   InputAliases] = {"0x" -> 
    RowBox[{InterpretationBox[
       StyleBox["\"0\"", ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
       Function[Null, 
        FromDigits[StringDrop[ToString@Unevaluated@#, 1], 16], 
        HoldAll]], "\[InvisibleApplication]", "\[InvisibleSpace]", 
      StyleBox["x", ShowAutoStyles -> False]}], ParentList};
AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] /. 
 Rule[a_, _] :> a

{"0x", "intt", "dintt", "sumt", "prodt", "dt", "ia", "cbrt", "surd", \
"ket", "bra", "braket", "delay", "grad", "del.", "delx", "del2", \
"notation", "notation>", "notation<", "symb", "infixnotation", \
"addia", "pattwraper", "madeboxeswraper"}
```

And the second:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = Inherited;
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   InputAliases] = {"0x" -> 
    RowBox[{InterpretationBox[
       StyleBox["\"0\"", ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
       Function[Null, 
        FromDigits[StringDrop[ToString@Unevaluated@#, 1], 16], 
        HoldAll]], "\[InvisibleApplication]", "\[InvisibleSpace]", 
      StyleBox["x", ShowAutoStyles -> False]}], Inherited};
AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] /. 
 Rule[a_, _] :> a

{"0x", Inherited}
```

We see that even though they are operationally similar, the `AbsoluteCurrentValue` result is different.

So I guess my question is, how do `ParentList` and `Inherited` differ outside of this small difference?

`ParentList` is obviously more scoped to list-type constructs, but why does it need to exist at all?

---

#### Extra Info:

Per Albert Retey's comment I checked whether either responded differently to upstream changes:

```
StyleSheetEdit["MyStyle1" -> "Input",
  {
   InputAliases -> {"0x" -> "\"\[SadSmiley]\"", ParentList}
   },
  "MakeCell" -> True
  ];
CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[""], "MyStyle1"]];
StyleSheetEdit["MyStyle2" -> "Input",
  {
   InputAliases -> {"0x" -> "\"\[SadSmiley]\"", Inherited}
   },
  "MakeCell" -> True
  ];
CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[""], "MyStyle2"]];
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = {"a" -> "\"b\""};
```

Both cells behaved entirely the same

Comment: What happens when you change the parent? I woud expect `Inherited` to reflect those changes but the explicit values that `ParentList` was creating would not change. Just guessing...

Comment: @AlbertRetey nope. Both seem to inherit fine.

Comment: ok, good to know :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its name is misleading, unfortunately, because it can be very useful.

A better name would be something around `ParentSequence`/`ParentArguments`. Here is one example:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules] = {"old" -> "value"};
cell = EvaluationCell[];

CurrentValue[cell, TaggingRules] = {ParentList, "new" -> "value"};
AbsoluteCurrentValue[cell, TaggingRules]
```

> ```
> {"old" -> "value", "new" -> "value"}
> ```

```
CurrentValue[cell, TaggingRules] = {Inherited, "new" -> "value"};
AbsoluteCurrentValue[cell, TaggingRules]
```

> ```
> {{"old" -> "value"}, "new" -> "value"}
> ```

So in this case you really want to use it.

Comment: Fantastic! I can think of so many situations where that would have made my life so much simpler.

Comment: @b3m2a1 There are exceptions though `CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], 
  ContextMenu] = {MenuItem["test", "test"], ParentList}`, I am not sure why. And sometimes  `Inherited` is handled gracefully anyway, probably when nested list does not  make sense.