# Merging list valued style options

Tags: stylesheet, style, inheritance

As shown in [Difference between ParentList and Inherited](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161682/5478) we can use `ParentList` to nicely merge additional rules.

It seems to work nicely when it comes to inheriting between 'objects' like: `$FrontEnd`, `$FrontEndSession`, *`_StyleSheet`*, `_Notebook(Object)`, `_Cell(Object)` etc.

I failed to make it work for `StyleData[style]` and `StyleData[style, env]` pair.

Here is an example:

```
CreateDocument[
  { Cell[BoxData@"", "Input"] }
 , StyleKeyMapping -> {ParentList, "&" -> "WolframAlphaShort"}
 , StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
     { Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]]
     , Cell[StyleData["Input", "Working"]
       , StyleKeyMapping -> {ParentList, "Tab" -> "WolframAlphaShort"}         
       ]
     }
   ]
 ]
```

By default when you hit `=`, in an empty `Input` cell, it will be converted to a `WolframAlphaShort` cell.

I wanted to add `&` and `Tab` to do the same. The former explicitly in a notebook and the latter via stylesheet.

They both work but the original `=` does not anymore.

This means the `Notebook's` spec correctly merged stylesheet's spec but the stylesheet resolution failed to merge spec from Default.nb.

Should it happen? Is there any way to proceed without explicitly including parent spec?

At the end I want all `&`, `Tab` and `=` to produce WAShort cell.

---

related:

[Updating styles which are based on styles changed in private stylesheet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108224/5478)

Comment: I think this is probably a key part of what's going on: `CreateDocument[{}, 
 StyleKeyMapping -> {ParentList, "&" -> "WolframAlphaShort"}]` doesn't cause the `&` to work, while the equivalent version putting `StyleKeyMapping -> {ParentList, "&" -> "WolframAlphaShort"}` in the stylesheet causes `&` to work but not `=`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I will dig up my tests later but as far as I remember it was quite inpredicatable, e.g. InputAliases was only preserving the parent one etc.